# Count the number of values between 2 inputted values with array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can somebody explain to me why this isn't working? The code is supposed to take two values that the user entered and count the number of values in the array list between the entered values. So for example, say the user entered 5 as their first value and 7 as their second value, because their are 3 values in the array between 5 and 7, an alert would pop up saying "total number of values = 3". But at the moment when I run the code it just keeps saying the total number of values is 0? Why is this?

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="num1"></input>
<input type="text" id="num2"></input>
<button onclick="start()"  type = "button">search</button>

<script src="array.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
var total = 0;
var num1 = "";
var num2 = "";
var array = [1,4,6,7,8,6];
for(var a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
    if(array[a] >= num1 && array[a] <= num2) {
         total++;
    }
}
alert("Total numbers of values = " + total);
```

Comment: Because num1 and num2 is 0. You are not getting the values from your input fields.

Answer (score 1):

- Drop your logic inside a function to execute only on button click.
- Catch the inputs with `getElementById` and store the values given by the user inside `num1` and `num2` variables.

```js
function start() {
  var total = 0;
  var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
  var array = [1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 6];
  for (var a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
    if (array[a] >= num1 && array[a] <= num2) {
      total++;
    }
  }
  alert("Total numbers of values = " + total);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num1">
<input type="text" id="num2">
<button onclick="start()" type="button">search</button>
```

You could also do it with `Array#filter`. This function will return an array with only the numbers which fulfill the conditions. Then, just check it `length` property to know how many elements remains.

```js
function start() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value,
      num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value,
      array = [1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 6],
      res = array.filter(v => v >= num1 && v <= num2).length;
      alert("Total numbers of values = " + res);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num1">
<input type="text" id="num2">
<button onclick="start()" type="button">search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

set `num1` and `num2` to `input` values.

```
var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok,You can just change here

```
var num1 = "";
var num2 = "";
```

Your code will be as like

```
var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
```